# MPLAB X IDE simulator docs

Tags: mplab

Can some one point me in the direction of any documentation on the simulator built into MPLAB X IDE. Trawled the net and can't find any. There used to be 4 or 5 chapters on the simulator in the older MPLAB IDE doc. The MPLAB X IDE doc "MPLAB_X_IDE_Users_Guide.pdf" does not have any info on the simulator.

Many thanks,
John

Comment: Maybe this example helps:https://microchipdeveloper.com/tls0101:lab2

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether they are still relevant to the current version, or are what you are looking for. But there are numerous hits to a search on:  mplab simulator. A few are:
http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/51025e.pdf

https://www.puntoflotante.net/EASY-GUIDE-TO-THE-MPLAB-IDE-SIMULATOR.pdf

https://www.microforum.cc/blogs/entry/6-using-the-mplab-x-simulator-to-debug-uart-code/

https://www.microchip.com/stellent/groups/sitecomm_sg/documents/devicedoc/en542701.pdf

https://www.microchip.com/forums/m1015713.aspx

https://microchipdeveloper.com/tls0101:lab2

Comment: Please remember the TO is working with MPLABX and NOT MPLAB. Most of your links are only for the simulator in MPLAB which is pretty old.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.
Since posting the question I've discovered that the information is available in the MPLAB X IDE help menu, useful but not as good as old fashioned pdfs. I had been looking for the docs in a separate pdf (which is available for the earlier MPLAB IDE) and before installing MPLAB X to see if it was worth installing. In the end I got desparate!